# Pulling information from two database tables

Tags: sql

[image]

[image]

So, what I want to do with these tables is sort employee names and department names by salary, but they are on seperate tables, so I assume I have to somehow use the WORKDEPT column and connect it to the DEPT table, but I'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tabA JOIN tabB ON tabA.DEPTNO = tabB.WORKDEPT ORDER BY salary
```